# How To Disassemble the LEGO Boost Hub?

Tags: disassembly, boost

I can get the hex screws off and pry apart the plastic tabs on the bottom plate, but for the life of me I can't un-clip the back tabs.

Any ideas on where to press/pry?

Comment: Yes/No?  Is this the Hub you're talking about? https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7ECr.jpg.

Comment: Yeah as rin said, clearing it up with be better

Answer (score 9):

[*Here*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D80B5Ei_cIw)'s a *YT* vid on the disassembly, but the still picture shots with no commentary may not be what you need for a good walk-thru.

I don't have a Hub, but wish we all had a pic to make sure we're talking about the same piece.

Regardless, I'm gonna take a crazy shot at it.  Let's Go!

We have two gray rectangles:

- *Big Gray Rectangle* on the Left.
- *Small Gray Rectangle* on the Right.

I think you're stuck here. (See the picture).

[image]

So, you took out the two hex screws, (two empty black holes on the *Big Gray Rectangle*), and you say you can't get further.  Correct?

Instead of trying to remove the *Big Gray Rectangle* plate, first remove the Phillips screw in the middle holding the *Small Gray Rectangle* down.

Look at the next picture.

[image]

See how the *Small Rectangle* has a lip design that overlaps, and locks down our *Big Gray Recky-reck*?

You should be good from here.

**EDIT**+++++++

***Real issue***: White Tabs won't release.

- Look at this next image of the *Big Gray Rectangle* removed below.

[image]

- Focus your attention to the white tabs.
- Do you see the notches on the tabs?
- The *inverse* of those notches are on the inside lip of the *Big Gray
  Rectangle*.
- When all notches are together it forms a *Mechanical Lock*.
- We have to disengage both tabs together.
- Position the entire piece like the picture below.
- Get two flat head screw drivers.
- Put both screw driver heads on the LEFT side of both tabs.
- Hold both screwdrivers in one fist like *Wolverine's* daughter.
- Now pivot to the LEFT which should separate the physical locking of
  the two pieces.
- You might need your other hand to lift *Big Gray    Rectangle*  up
  and off.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Rin, thanks for responding.
I had previously found this video but as you said the still picture walkthrough is not ideal...
  I did get as far as you described (ie removing the battery compartment). My problem comes next. The big rectangular grey plate left is held in place not just by the screws (that I removed) but also by plastic tabs/clips. In your picture above you can see 6 grey ones (2 on north edge, 2 south edge,2 two on the left hand corners) and two white ones on the left side.
 Its these white ones that are my problem.I don't know which way to push/pry them in order to unlatch

Comment: Alright, I got you ;).  Thanks for coming back with the extra details explaining exactly where you're stuck. I'm going to add a picture and explain exactly how to get around the white tabs.  Give me 15 mins.  We'll get through it easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same last night because the internal motor position A did not work. I ended up pushing a small screwdriver from in between the housing, not from the tabs since I felt that would deform the plastic even more.

Fun fact: to solve my encoder issue, I simply had to nudge the sensor a bit closer to the perforated wheel, using some tweezers. I wonder how it ever worked - or stopped working - in the first place.

Here are some pictures from the parts for future reference:
[image: channel side]
[image: butt]
[image: base]
[image: lid]
[image: top]
[image: channel top]